# SparkAppHandle State is LOST after submit, but the driver runs flawlessly

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using spark java API to submit a driver to a local Spark cluster (1 master + 1 worker). 
After calling startApplication with a Listener attached, the first call to stateChanged gives the LOST state.

The Driver is submitted OK and runs fine in the worker.

I've tried with a waiting loop instead of a Listener.

I've tried with Spark versions 2.3.1 and 2.4.3.

I've tried in OSX and Ubuntu.

I've tried changing the Spark Master Host to the machine's IP instead of the name.

```
SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher(env)
    .setAppResource(path)
    .setMainClass("full.package.name.RTADriver")
    .setMaster("spark://" + sparkMasterHost + ":" + sparkMasterPort)
    .setAppName("rta_scala_app_")
    .setDeployMode("cluster")
    .setConf("spark.ui.enabled", "true")
    .addAppArgs(runnerStr)
    .setVerbose(true);

SparkAppHandle handle = launcher.startApplication();

while (!handle.getState().equals(SparkAppHandle.State.FINISHED)){
    System.out.println("Wait Loop: App_ID: " + handle.getAppId() + " state: " +  handle.getState());
    Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```

**Logs of the System.out on my code:**

```
First State App_ID: null state: UNKNOWN
Wait Loop: App_ID: null state: UNKNOWN
Wait Loop: App_ID: null state: LOST
Wait Loop: App_ID: null state: LOST
...
```

**Important spark submit logs:**

```
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverClient' on port 52077.
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:54 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.10.0.179:7077 after 34 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:54 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver successfully submitted as driver-20190604112754-0030
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:54 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... waiting before polling master for driver state
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: ... polling master for driver state
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: State of driver-20190604112754-0030 is RUNNING
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:59 INFO ClientEndpoint: Driver running on 10.10.0.179:49705 (worker-20190603154544-10.10.0.179-49705)
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
INFO: 19/06/04 11:27:59 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/90/pgndgkk11lj0qb4q5qw_f03c0000gn/T/spark-8d8d92b9-8d0c-43a1-8bb9-3d08f1519c53
Wait Loop: App_ID: null state: LOST
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same situation. My guess is due to the deploy mode "cluster", the spark driver process was running in a different host with spark launcher process; hence the launcher process "lost" connection with the spark app.