# Spark Launcher returning LOST state in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Trying to launch a Spark application which is launched perfectly fine but I am getting the state as LOST from the handler.
`

```
SparkAppHandle handler = new SparkLauncher()
                         .setSparkHome(spark_home_path)
                         .setJavaHome(java_home)
                         .setAppName("TEST")
                         .setDeployMode("cluster")
                         .setAppResource(jar_path)
                         .setMainClass(main_class)
                         .setMaster(spark_master_rest_url)
                         .setVerbose(true)
                         .startApplication(new SparkAppHandle.Listener(){
                           @Override
                           public void stateChanged(SparkAppHandle sh){
                           System.out.println(sh.getState() + "is current state");
                           }
                           @Override
                           public void infoChanged(SparkAppHandle sh){
                           System.out.println(sh.getState() + " is info");
                           }
});
     while(!handler.getState().isFinal()){
       System.out.println("Wait:Loop APP_ID : "+handler.getAppId()+" state: "+handler.getState());
       Thread.sleep(10000);
     }
```

`

The state continuously prints LOST and AppId as null, irrespective of the state of job which is finished. Can someone please guide here ?

Comment: Same here. This looks reasonable as an explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56442307/sparkapphandle-state-is-lost-after-submit-but-the-driver-runs-flawlessly